# What does the "en" stand for in "en fait voler les attaches"?

Tags: grammaire, antécédent

I read this little short story about a knight killing a dragon and I came across this sentence:

> Le monstre a senti l'atteinte : il lance ses griffes contre l'écu, les y enfonce et en fait voler les attaches.

I first translated as:

> The monster felt the feat (getting struck by a sword): it threw its claws against the shield, pushing them (into the shield) and...

But I couldn't understand the "en fait voler les attaches".
At first I thought it meant "en fait" as "in fact" or "actually", but that doesn't make sense since if it was an adverb it'd be followed by a conjugated verb. And the word "attaches", I couldn't find a single translation on the internet that makes sense here. I feel like it wants to say "Making the (something) fly, but even if I knew the noun, I wouldn't know what "en" was referring to.

For context:

> Le dragon avait deux cornes au front, les oreilles longues et velues,les yeux étincelants à fleur de tête tels des charbons ardents, le mufle haut dressé comme celui d’une guivre, la langue hors de la gueule, crachant de toutes parts le feu et le venin, le corps écailleux,des griffes de lion et la queue d’un serpent. Le monstre a vu Tristan : il rugit et enfle tout son corps. Le preux rassemble ses forces et, se couvrant de son écu, broche son destrier  avec une telle vigueur que le coursier,tout hérissé de peu, bondit pourtant contre la bête.
>   La lance de Tristan heurte les écailles et vole en éclats. Aussitôt le preux tire son épée,la brandit et en assène un coup terrible sur la tête du dragon, mais sans même entamer le cuir. Le monstre a senti l’atteinte : il lance ses griffes contre l’écu, les y enfonce et en fait voler les attaches. La poitrine découverte, Tristan le requiert encore de l’épée et le frappe sur les flancs d’un coup si violent que l’air en retentit. Vainement : il ne peut l’entamer.
>   Alors,le dragon vomit par les naseaux un double jet de flammes : le haubert de Tristan noircit comme charbon,son cheval s’abat et meurt.Mais aussitôt relevé,Tristan enfonce la pointe de son épée dans la gueule du monstre :elle y pénètre toute et lui transperce le cœur. Le dragon pousse une dernière fois son cri horrible et meurt.
>   Quand Tristan le vit mort, il lui coupa la langue jusqu’à la racine, car il voulait la conserver comme un trophée de victoire, et il la dissimula dans sa chausse,entre la chair et l’étoffe.

---

Béroul, *Tristan et Iseult*, Chapitre 6 : « La Victoire sur le dragon d'Irlande »

Answer (score 5):

*En* is a personal pronoun, 3rd person indirect object. It stands here for *écu*.

One way you could rephrase the sentence would be :

- > le dragon enfonce ses griffes dans l'écu et il fait voler les attaches de l'écu.

  il enfonce ses griffes **dans l'écu** → il  **y** enfonce ses griffes.

  You use *y* to replace a place name: *l'écu.*
- > il fait voler les attaches **de l'écu** → il **en** fait voler les attaches.

  You use **en** because the noun *écu* is introduced by *de*.

---

***[Attache](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/attache)***
It is a noun, from the verb ***attacher***.

Avec ses griffes le monstre déchire les attaches qui servent à fixer l'écu.
 → The monster uses its claws to tear the fasterners that hold the shield.

Answer (score 1):

In this sentence, *en* stands for *écu*, the phrase could be:

> il lance ses griffes contre l'écu.
>   Il enfonce ses griffes dans l'écu.
>   Il fait voler les attaches de l'écu.

Comment: I didn't know that "en" could be used like that. So could I say "L'écran de mon iPhone est cassé. Mon frère en cassé l'écran."

Comment: @MarcoRubenAbuyuanLlanes: Yes, you could. But you'd better to write: *Mon iPhone est cassé, mon frère en a cassé l'écran.*